# SQL query to append values not contained in second table

Tags: sql

I have table A and table B with different number of columns but both containing a column with IDs. Table A contains more complete list of IDs and table B contains some of the IDs from the table A.

I would like to return resulting table B with original information plus appended IDs that are missing in B but contained in A. For these appended rows, other columns should be blank while column with IDs in B should just contain missing ID values.

Comment: can please share schema of your table .

Comment: Add schema of your tables. But it looks like for right outher join...

Comment: Sample data and desired results would be quite helpful.  You should also tag your question with the database you are using.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simple solution `UNION ALL`, with `NOT EXISTS`:

```
select b.id, b.c1, ..., b.cn
from b
UNION ALL
select distinct a.id, null, ..., null       -- should be same number of columns as in the above select
from a
where not exists (select 1 from b where b.id = a.id)
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you described `left join`:

```
select *
from b left join
     a
     using (id)
```